# How to make S4 class from another package available to my package?

Tags: r, devtools, r-dbi

I'm following [Hadley's guide to implement a DBI backend](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/vignettes/backend.html), which instructs me to build S4 classes that inherit from DBI classes.

From the instructions, to make the DBI classes available, it seems that I only have to list `DBI` as an import in the `DESCRIPTION` file.

However, even after doing so, I still get the error

```
 Error in reconcilePropertiesAndPrototype(name, slots, prototype, superClasses,  : 
  no definition was found for superclass “DBIDriver” in the specification of class “KazamDriver”
```

If I explicit attach `DBI` with `library` then this problem go away, but of course one shouldn't use `library` in package code.

My code:

```
# DBI-backend.R 
setClass("KazamDriver", contains = "DBIDriver")

# DESCRIPTION
Imports:
  DBI (>= 0.3.0),
  methods
```

Comment: Have you seen the new [`RKazam` package](https://github.com/rstats-db/RKazam) (a boilerplate DBI package) and the new [`DBItest` package](https://github.com/rstats-db/DBItest) (a test suite for DBI backends)? What DBMS are you implementing a DBI backend for?

Comment: Yes, I was following that package's tutorial. The bug I'm encountering turns out to be `devtools::document()` not modifying `NAMESPACE`. Therefore `DBI` is not imported via `NAMESPACE` despite my using `@import DBI`. So it's a `devtools::document()` bug, not a DBI / DBItest bug.

Answer (score 1):

The Imports field in the DESCRIPTION file does not actually import anything. It only makes sure that the listed packages are installed when a user installs your package.

Instead, use NAMESPACE to make other packages or functions available to be used in your package. Also, don't edit NAMESPACE by hand, but use Roxygen2 (details [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html)).

For this particular case, it means

```
#' @import DBI
setClass("KazamDriver", contains = "DBIDriver")
```

Comment: I tried this and the error didn't go away. I later realized I had forgotten to include the package manually in the `Imports:` section of the `DESCRIPTION` file. This isn't done by roxygen2/devtools